# Perl LWP::Simple File.txt in Array not spaces

Tags: perl

The file does not have spaces and do i need to keep every word in the corresponding array, 
content in var, the file is more large, but this is ok.

```
my $file = "http://www.ausa.com.ar/autopista/carteleria/plano/mime.txt"; 

&VPM4362=008000&VPM4381=FFFFFF&VPM4372=FFFFFF&VPM4391=008000&VPM4382=FFFF00&VPM4392=FF0000&VPM4182=FFFFFF&VPM4181=FFFF00&VPM4402=FFFFFF&VPM4401=FFFF00&VPM4412=008000&VPM4411=FF0000&VPM4422=FFFFFF&VPM4421=FFFFFF&VPM4322=FFFF00&CPMV001_1_Ico=112&CPMV001_1_1=AHORRE 15%&CPMV001_1_2=ADHIERASE AUPASS&CPMV001_1_3=AUPASS.COM.AR&CPMV002_1_Ico=0&CPMV002_1_1=ATENCION&CPMV002_1_2=RADARES&CPMV002_1_3=OPERANDO&CPMV003_1_Ico=0&CPMV003_1_1=ATENCION&CPMV003_1_2=RADARES&CPMV003_1_3=OPERANDO&CPMV004_1_Ico=255&CPMV004_1_1= &CPMV004_1_2=&CPMV004_1_3=&CPMV05 _1_Ico=0&CPMV05 _1_1=ATENCION&CPMV05 _1_2=RADARES&CPMV05 _1_3=OPERANDO&CPMV006_1_Ico=0&CPMV006_1_1=ATENCION&CPMV006_1_2=RADARES&CPMV006_1_3=OPERANDO&CPMV007_1_Ico=0&CPMV007_1_1=ATENCION&CPMV007_1_2=RADARES&CPMV007_1_3=OPERANDO&CPMV08 _1_Ico=0&CPMV08 _1_1=ATENCION&CPMV08
```

the code.

```
#!/bash/perl .T
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;

my $file = "http://www.ausa.com.ar/autopista/carteleria/plano/mime.txt";
my $mime = get($file);

my @new;

foreach my $line ($mime) {
    $line =~ s/&/ /g;
    push(@new, $line);
}
print "$new[0]\n";
```

Try this way but when I start the array is equal to (all together)

the output I need

```
print "$new[1]\n";
VPM4381=FFFFFF
```

Comment: Sorry, but your explanation is unclear, and you didn't demonstrate the problem. Start by showing a sample input and what output you expect from that input.

Comment: The file *has* spaces in it and consists of a single line. So your program is correct, the input is not.

Comment: When I delete character i open space to save in array then start 0 element but come out all the content together

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using `unshift` and not `push`? You're turning your values over that way. The last element will end up the first one in `@new`.

Comment: tip bad, in really is push!! :D

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to substitute on `&`, you want to [`split`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#split) on `&`.

```
@new = split /&/, $line;
```

Comment: Still, the first element is `''`, so you might want to go `unshift @new, grep { $_ ne '' } split(/&/, $line);` to get rid of that.